# Excel convert crosstab data to longitudinal based on unique ID

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel filed arranged in crosstab format that I need to transform longitudinally.

What I have:

```
|-id-|-f1-|-f2-|-f3-|
|-1--|-a--|-b--|-c--|
|-1--|-a--|-x--|-y--|
|-2--|-1--|null|-9--|
|-2--|-f--|-1--|null|      
|-2--|-a--|-v--|-2--|
```

What I need:

```
|-id-|-f1-|-f2-|-f3-|-id-|-f1-|-f2-|-f3-|-id-|-f1-|-f2-|-f3-|
|-1--|-a--|-b--|-c--|-1--|-a--|-x--|-y--|null|null|null|null|
|-2--|-1--|null|-9--|-2--|-f--|-1--|null|-2--|-a--|-v--|-2--|
```

I need a macro or VBA code that I can run quickly and easily on hundreds of rows/columns and automagically put the longitudinally arranged data in a new sheet.

I found this online.  It coverts the file exactly as I want it to, however, you manually have to select the rows to combine.  I am looking for something that will find the unique ids and do the condensing by itself.

```
Sub TransformOneRow()
'Updateby20131120
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Ranges to be transform :", xTitleId, 
InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Paste to (single cell):", xTitleId, 
Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xRows = InputRng.Rows.Count
xCols = InputRng.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To xRows
    InputRng.Rows(i).Copy OutRng
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(0, xCols + 0)
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

--Update--

I still have not figured out how to do this with macro, but here is a decent workaround that isn't too labor intensive or time consuming, in case anyone else has this same problem:

https://www.excel-university.com/combine-rows-into-a-delimited-list/

And as a supplement to address some issues with the above method:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Error-DataFormat-Error-We-couldn-t-convert-to-Number-Details/m-p/150897#M65221

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub TryThis()

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRows As Long
Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select Range:", "Kutools For Excel", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
Set xRg = Range(Intersect(xRg, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Address)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
xRows = xRg.Rows.Count
For I = xRows To 2 Step -1
For J = 1 To I - 1
If xRg(I, 1).Value = xRg(J, 1).Value And J <> I Then
For K = 2 To xRg.Columns.Count
If xRg(J, K).Value <> "" Then
If xRg(I, K).Value = "" Then
xRg(I, K) = xRg(J, K).Value
Else
xRg(I, K) = xRg(I, K).Value & "," & xRg(J, K).Value
End If
End If
Next
xRg(J, 1).EntireRow.Delete
I = I - 1
J = J - 1
End If
Next
Next
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Also, consider using Power Query, which you can get from the link below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

Comment: Thanks ryguy72.  Both of these are working perfectly for automatically grouping based on the id in column a, however, it's not condensing all the data into one row. It appears to only be condensing columns A and B.  I have hundreds of columns I need condensed into one row.  Is there a way to have it prompt for a range, or to have it look at all columns with data?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I changed my original post.  This should do what you want.  Please mark it as helpful if it helps you.

Comment: Instead of comma separating the values in the same cell, I need the data appended at the end of the same line.  So for example:

    ID | A | B | C | D
    1   | 1 | 2 | a | b
    1   | 3 | 4 | x | y

Should come out like this:

    ID | A | B | C | D
    1   | 1 | 2 |  a | b | 3 | 4 | x | y

And not like this:

     ID |   A |  B  | C  | D
     1   | 1,3| 2,4| a,x| b,y